# How to make all arraylists of same size in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I got five ArrayLists with different lengths but when I concatenate all the array lists, I get an array index out of bound exception as the items in a all the array list are not the same. I want to either include null when the item not found or make the array list of same size. How to achieve this in android.. please help me with some example and thanks in advance

arraylist 1 = 25 items
attaylist 2 = 35 items
arraylits 3 = 5 items
arraylist 4 = 13 items
arraylist 5 = 40 items.

when i display all items in one view (eg.web view) i could scroll upto 5 items when scroll to 6th item i get exception. how to overcome this. please help

here is my code whre i parse and add to lists.

Comment: Please share your code.. What have you tried earlier..

Comment: how exactly are you concatenating your `ArrayList`s?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know but see if this helps:

```
package your.package
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    setContentView(tv);

    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add(4);

    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    b.add(5);
    b.add(6);
    b.add(7);        

    a.addAll(b);


    String p = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        p = String.format("%s, %d", p, a.get(i));
    }

    tv.setText(p);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to see what the problem is if your code is posted.  If you want to return null when you get an out of bounds exception, though, something like this should do it:

```
try {
  //your code that's throwing index out of bounds

  //this block should include as little of your code as possible
  //for example, don't put a for loop in here --
  //  put this inside the for loop if you can.
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
  return null;
  // or do what you need to do with the null
}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)'s some introductory material on exception handling in case you'd like to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

this is not android.. its pure java issue
technically , arraylist is a kind of mutable array... 
just check where the index you are calling is less than the size of arrayList if yes,go concatenating, if not so its you are out bound exception..
or you can try to convert your arraylist to array like this (suppose data type is String):

```
String mArray[]=mArrayList.toArray(new String[SIZE]);
```

this will assign null to empty elements in case mArrayList size < mArray

good luck

Comment: thanks for helping me,  i have added code please check my code and help me please

Answer (score 2):

Make some Default values in your class
like

```
public class BOOK {
String BId="";
String BTitle="";
String prelimTitle="";
String prelimIntro="";
String prelimInsight="";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to have another data structure, and add list of that item into main Book Structure, new Datastructre may be:

```
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
        if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("BOOK")) {
            book.setInsightList(insightList);
            book.setcasestudyList(casestudyList);
            book.setquotesList(quoteList);
            book.setoneminwonderList(oneminwonderList);
            book.setsecretList(secretList);
            bookList.add(book);
            Intro.book = book;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("chapter")) {
                            if(objInsight==null)
                                objInsight=new INSIGHT();
                            listInsights.add(objInsight);
                            objInsight=null;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("secret")) {
            secretList.add(secret);
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("prelim")) {
            secretList.add(secret);
            this.prelim = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("prelimTitle")) {
            this.prelimTitle = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("prelimIntro")) {
            this.prelimIntro = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString()
                .equals("prelimInsight")) {
            this.prelimInsight = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString()
                .equals("prelimContent")) {
            this.prelimContent = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString()
                .equals("chapterIntro")) {
            secretList.add(secret);
            this.chapterIntro = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("bold")) {
            this.chapterIntrobold = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("secretIntro")) {
            this.secretIntro = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("insight")) {

        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("caseStudy")) {
            this.caseStudy = false;
            casestudyList.add(casestudy);
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("oneMinute")) {
            this.oneMinute = false;
            oneminwonderList.add(oneminwonder);
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString().equals("quote")) {
            quoteList.add(quotes);
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString()
                .equals("quoteContent")) {
            this.quoteContent = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString()
                .equals("quoteCitation")) {
            this.quoteCitation = false;
        } else if (xmlpullparser.getName().toString()
                .equals("secretContent")) {
            this.secretContent = false;
        }

        break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You got that exception there may be not enough space in to thst arraylist.
Supose there are three arraylist like a with size 10,b with size 10 and c with size 10.

Now you are adding the that all arraylist to the ArrayList z with size 10 then there are total 30 data but the index are only 10. So it cause the IndexOutofBount exception.

**Solution**

So to solve that you have to take the new ArrayList z with the size like sum of that all three arraylist size.
and then add the three arrayList data to that arrayList.

You can give the Size to the ArrayList with below code.

```
ArrayList<Integer>[size] arrayOfLists = new ArrayList<Integer>[size]();
```

Hope it will help you.

If not then let me know.

Enjoy. :))